# Auto Id for wpf control

Tags: .net, wpf, controls, uniqueidentifier

Is there a unique Id for a WPF control?
This Id needs to be permanent and not to be change if I rename the control name or change the position?

Answer (score 2):

If you want an Id that doesn't change when you rename a WPF control you can always use the

[AutomationProperties.AutomationId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationproperties.automationid.aspx)

From msdn

> Gets or set the string that uniquely identifies the specified element.

If even that doesn't satisfy your requirement you can invent your own attached dependency property. The benefit of the AutomationId property is that you can use the UI automation library and [AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.automationidproperty.aspx) to find and control that UI element

Comment: ok , this is good , there is something like this for winForm too?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking that whether WPF auto generates a unique id for each control, then the answer is NO. As suggested by parapura, you can use AutomationIdProperty to give an id to a control (or to an instance of a control) but you have to manually make sure that the ids you give are unique.